# Json call on unauthorized url returns Unexpected token < in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Making ajax call:

```
let json = this._super(url, type, options);
```

On return it will return login page(HTML code) since url is unauthorized the json returned is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
   at JSON.parse ()
   at jQuery.parseJSON (jquery.js:8520)
   at ajaxConvert (jquery.js:8846)
   at done (jquery.js:9264)
   at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:9718)

Errors occured: ember-metal.js:3992 TypeError: Cannot read property ‘get’ of undefined
   at adapter.js:28
   at tryCatcher (rsvp.js:215)
   at invokeCallback (rsvp.js:393)
   at publish (rsvp.js:379)
   at publishRejection (rsvp.js:314)
   at rsvp.js:14

ember-metal.js:3992 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
   at JSON.parse ()    
   at jQuery.parseJSON (jquery.js:8520)
   at ajaxConvert (jquery.js:8846)
   at done (jquery.js:9264)
   at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:9718)
```

What may be the reason?

Comment: You have invalid JSON. Please may your provide a small example of the JSON being used?

Comment: Hii @evolutionxbox, I have metioned that returned type is login page(html) file not json....

Comment: I don't think you can use `JSON.parse` with HTML...

Comment: yes, I too did'nt use JSON.parse the output of the line itself let json = this._super(url, type, options); itself is SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 , since html page is returned

Comment: I don't know where this conversion occurs

Answer (score 0):

If the resource requires authentication, then you're likely getting redirected to a login page in which case you're trying to parse the HTML code of the page as JSON.

Check the `Content-Type` header of the response to verify the format of the data before trying to parse it, JSON typically uses the MIME type `application/json`, whereas HTML uses `text/html`.

If server requires authentication to access the resource, then you'll typically need to set an `Authorization` header in your request with appropriate credentials.

Comment: hiii Mike, Thanks for the reply, since it is the ajax call it cannot be redirected from server side, so we need to redirect by checking in client side, this is the case where login page itself getting returned in response where ember tries to parse it as json and this expection occurs

Comment: The server can redirect unauthenticated requests even if they originate from XHR calls.  This may take the form of a `301` Moved Permanently response which has to be followed client-side, or just return the content of the redirection, possibly with a `401` Unauthorized response.  Checking the response status code and `Content-Type` will tell you whether the call has succeeded and contains the expected data, or has failed and needs the appropriate `Authorization` header set.

Comment: Hii Mike, Even this returns html code for ajax call it dosen't redirect to login page any other idea???

Comment: Have a look at the content of the HTML page that's being returned, it may have some information in there as to why the call is being rejected.

Comment: the call is rejected because user's session timed out, soo login page is returned...